# %20 in filename, browser sees whitespaces. How to avoid that?

Tags: .htaccess, url, replace, whitespace, filenames

I have imported images to my own server. One of the many filenames has `%20` in them, e.g. `50128%202789%20001V%20500.jpg`. However the browser sees it as `50128 2789 001V 500.jpg`, so it won't display the image.

What solution can I use, to display the image properly?

Answer (score 2):

"%20" is a percent-encoding for a space, and has special meaning in a URL.  Basically, you can't use spaces in a URI or URL, and have to replace them with a code to comply with the rules.  Things that read URLs (the server for example) translate them back.

Unfortunately, that means if you have a filename containing this sequence, it will be mistaken for a percent-encoded space, as you're seeing.

The solution is to also percent-encode the '%'.  The percent-encoding for a '%' character is "%25".

In your example, the name "50128%202789%20001V%20500.jpg" has to be encoded to "50128%25202789%2520001V%2520500.jpg"  so that those '%' characters are not mistaken for spaces.

There are of course other things that get encoded.  The rules are defined in [the URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).